# It was A productive week or it was THE productive week.?

Tags: articles

> It was A productive week.
>   It was THE productive week.

What is the correct way to say and why?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer you are looking for is probably *a*.

If you say *a*, you could be talking about any productive week that has occurred.

If you say *the*, it must be clear to the reader which productive week you are talking about. For example, if there has only been one productive week, then it is clear to the reader which productive week you are referencing, so you could use *the*.

However, you are probably looking for the first case.

Answer (score 1):

[This explains the difference.](http://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-an-vs-the.htm) **A** and **an** are both indefinite articles, (non-specific). **Productive** being what it's non-specific to.

Here are other examples of using **a** or **an**

> I want **a** phone, (any)
>
> I want **a** car, (any)
>
> I want **an** ice cream cone, (any)

Now if we use **the** here, (definite) then it would be specific, **productive** being what it's specific to.

Here are other examples of using **the**

> I want **the** phone (specific)
>
> I want **the** car (specific)
>
> I want **the** ice cream cone (specific)

So the difference between them is wether or not the week you refer to is specific.

Comment: I will add, that  using **the** makes the sentence seem incomplete,  "it was **the** productive week..." Is seems like saying something like "it was **the** productive week...that made our company successful." would improve your sentence, if you are using **the**